# How to change permission of shellscript in databricks

Tags: azure, shell, databricks, azure-databricks

I am having a shell script in the DBFS. When I am executing it, it gives permission error 13.

I tried to change the permission using '`chmod 755 name.sh`'. But, no changes actually take place.

Could anyone help on the same?

## Tried Code:

```
%cd /dbfs/FileStore/tables/ 
%sh chmod 775 wrapper.sh

%sh chmod +x wrapper.sh

%sh ls -ltr 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2819 Oct 28 12:01 wrapper.sh
```

Comment: Do you get any error message ?

Comment: No error message from notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot change permissions of files located in databricks filesystem (DBFS).

I have tried all the possibilities to change the file permissions located in dbfs and finally result in no success. Then, I have checked with product team for the solution. An d they have confirmed that, you cannot change the permissions of any files located in dbfs and asked ro run the script with following cmdlet "`bash /dbfs/script.sh`".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will try and let you know.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to run the script with bash command but fails with exit code 2 and 126. Can I run the script from anywhere in databricks or should I upload it to bin folder ?